# asp.net : Get the value from textarea

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am creating one form for image upload drag and drop through jquery.

when i dragged one image to aspx form, that time that image
preview and title ( textarea ) and desc ( textarea ) created to aspx page.

after entered the title and desc, 
it is saved to database when i click save button.

i couldn't get the textarea control in c# (code behind ) ?

textarea does not added directly to aspx page. it is is dynamically added through jquery so????

in jquery textarea added

```
<textarea id="txtImagename1" runat="server" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
```

code behind

```
HtmlTextArea txtImageupload = (HtmlTextArea)(frm.FindControl("txtImagename1"));
string imagename = txtImageupload.Value;
```

Comment: have you tried `txtImageupload.Text`

Comment: ya i tried it is getting error. because it is not textbox..

Comment: when i run txtImageupload this is getting NULL...

Comment: Try this string imagename = txtImageupload.innerText;

Comment: first ' txtImageupload ' is getting null so getting error object refference not set to on instance....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
Request.Form["txtImagename1"]
```

No need of `runat="server"`

Also, add `name="txtImagename1"`

```
<textarea id="txtImagename1" name="txtImagename1" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: if its working for you. You should accept it as answer. So, that it can help others in future.

Comment: Note that it is the "name" attribute of the textarea element that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Add `name` attribute to the Dynamic control :

```
 <textarea id="txtImagename1" name="txtImagename1" runat="server" rows="1" cols="50">
 </textarea>
```

from your codebehind :

```
Request.Form["txtImagename1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox txtImageName = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtImagename1");
string strFromTextArea = txtImageName.Text;
```

Note :

- "Page" should be container of your textarea  control. If your textarea is in panel, use your panel object instead of Page.
- Multiple lines textbox control is textarea in HTML control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" id="description" >
</textarea>
```